# How to add key value-pair to a Object?

Tags: object, dart, dart-mirrors

I want to update my Object by adding a more key-value pair.

```
Object options = {
  "first_name": "Nitish",
  "last_name" : "Singh"
}
```

after initializing the Object I want to add one more key and value. Is there any way to do this.

after adding one more key-value pair my object will look like this

```
options = {
  "first_name" : "Nitish",
  "last_name"  : "Singh"
  "middle_name": "Kumar"
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can assign to a Map using the indexing operator

```
options['middle_name'] = 'Kumar';
```

`{}` is a `Map` literal to create a `Map` instance.
The result allows you to use all methods of `Map` like [remove](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/Map/remove.html)

Comment: I got this error : The operator '[]=' isn't defined for the class 'Object'

Comment: That's an analyzer warning. Use `var` or `final` instead of `Object` to have the type inferred or use `Map` or `Map<String,String>` to specify a concrete type yourself. See also my updated answer.

Comment: If you don't want to overwrite a value if the key already exists, then there is also `map.putIfAbsent(key, () => valueIfAbsent);`